# Finiteness of an integral of a complex valued function

Tags: integration, complex-numbers

I am wondering whether the following integral is finite ($i$ is the imaginary number and $|\cdot|$ denotes the absolute value):

$$ \int_{\mathbb{R}}|e^{(2-iu)^{1.5}}|du<\infty\,?$$

It's been years since I studied complex analysis and I am a bit stuck. The problem I am dealing with is actually a little more complicated, but if I can get help with this one I may have they key. Thanks in advance!

Comment: It depends on what you mean by $(2-iu)^{1.5}$. It may mean main branch of $\sqrt{2-iu}$ to the 3rd power, main branch of $\sqrt{(2-iu)^3}$, $|2-iu|^{3/2}e^{3 i \operatorname{Arg}(2-iu)/2}$...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The integral converges, and is finite. The details are below.

(*Complex numbers reminder*: For any complex $z=a+ib$ we have $e^z=e^{a+ib}=e^ae^{ib}$
and so $|e^z|=|e^a|=|e^{\rm{Re}(z)}|$ where Re$(z)$ is the real part of $z$. Recall that $|e^{ib}|=1$ for any real $b$.)

Elementary computation with complex numbers gives:

$$(2-iu)^{3/2}=(4 + u^2)^{3/4}\cos[3/2\cdot\hbox{Arg}(2 - iu)] + 
 i(4 + u^2)^{3/4}\sin[3/2\cdot\hbox{Arg}(2 - iu)]$$

for the absolute value of the exponent we only want the real part:

$$|e^{(2-iu)^{3/2}}|=e^{(4 + u^2)^{3/4}\cos[3/2\cdot\rm{Arg}(2 - iu)]}$$

Since the function is even in $u$, it suffices to check what happens for $u>0$. As it happens, the function $u\to\rm{Arg}(2-i u)$ is negative on $(0,\infty)$ and $\lim_{u\to\infty}\rm{Arg}(2-i u)=-{\pi\over 2}$, so the integrand is of the order of magnitude of $e^{-u^{3/2}}$, and so the integral converges.